# my button can't be clicked because of some properties in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

help, I created a card with a button in it, in the card section I used the css property pointer-events: none; so that the button cannot be clicked because of that property, can I click the button without deleting the property pointer-events: none;
thank you

[image]

Comment: it would be helpful if you share the snippet of your code

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with the help of bootstrap, you need to give a mentor column class col-sm-12 and rest of the icons class col-sm-6

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@media** queries to set the width and height of each icon.

```js
 @media (max-width: 786px) { 
         .icon1{
             width: 30px;
             height: 30px;
          }
    
      }
```

Media queries are useful when you want to modify your site or app depending on a device's screen size. Now the above **css** will work if the maximum size of the screen is **786px**